# openserver, открыть сайт с другого устройства в сети

Tags: openserver

Как открыть мне свой сайт на openserver'е с телефона по вайфай-сети?
В поисках наткнулся на такую [статью](http://mbaev.com/content/kak-otkryt-sait-dla-lokalnoi-seti). Это очевидные действия, которые я и сам проделал до этого, но безрезультатно.

Что я делал:
В настройках опенсервера указал внешний айпи.
Добавил алиас (внешний айпи => site.loc)

Что-то видимо не сделал ещё, да?

Comment: У вас в сети должен быть dns сервер, который отдает ip вашего сайта другим компьютерам в сети. Но так как у вас его нет, то либо обращайтесь к вашему сайту с других компов по ip, либо пропишите соответствие `ip <--> сайт` в файлах hosts на всех компьютерах сети (для Windows).

Comment: @Visman я и пробую обращаться по IP, типа такого: `http://192.168.0.109/` Или не так? Браузер телефона некоторое время думает, но не грузит ничего.

Comment: Так у вас может быть firewall на компьютере блокирует входящие или openserver.

Comment: @Visman точно, eset использовал персональный файервол, который блокировал доступ.